# How to publish Domain Events from Domain objects using StructureMap and current request container?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, structuremap, domain-events

I'm trying to create an application with DDD, implementing **Domain Events**, using **Entity Framework** and **StructureMap** for dependency injection.

I created an abstraction of UnitOfWork and Repositories. Obviously, the IUnitOfWork implementation encapsulates the DbContext, and all instances are injected by StructureMap (Nested Container's per HTTP request), so the IUnitOfWork injected in all repositories (Also injected) are the same instance (By the way, for the same reason, only one instance of DbContext is created per request).

UnitOfWork implementation is like this...

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public EFUnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        Context = dbContext;
    }

    ...
```

... and repositories are like..

```
public class BaseRepository<T, TId> : IRepository<T, TId>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    // All the repositories created are automaticaly injected 
    // with the same IUnitOfWork instance during the request.
    public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    ...
```

All this works well, and I can manage my changes in the context using my IUnitOfWork instance.

```
public class UsersService : IUsersService
{

        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public UsersService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public override CreateUserUseCaseResult HandleExecute(CreateUserUseCaseRequest input)
        {
            var user = Mapper.Map<User>(input.User);
            _userRepository.Insert(user);

            ...

            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

            return new CreateUserUseCaseResult
            {
                User = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(user)
            };
        }
    }
```

**The Problem**

I want to implement Domain Events, and the idea is to have an static class with the method to publish the events in this way:

```
    DomainEvents.Publish(new TheDomainEvent() { Data = "something" });
```

So I can use it inside of domain objects like Entities.

But for it to work I need not only access to my container instance (where all event handlers are registered), I need access to the current nested container instance to share the same IUnitOfWork instance (I don't need the IUnitOfWork directly, but I need to have the same instance injected in all repositories) so any operation inside the event handlers can be performed on the same DbContext).

So... How can I have an static class with a publish method, to be available in the domain?

For now, I temporary worked around the problem injecting a IDomainBus instance on the services, so the current nested container is used to create the event handler instances.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
        private readonly IDomainBus _domainBus;

        public UsersService(IDomainBus domainBus, ...)
        {
            _domainBus= domainBus;
        }

        public void PerformSomeOperation(OperationRequest data)
        {
            ...

            _domainBus.Publish(new SomeOperationPerformed() { Data = data });

            ...
```

But I can't use this solution if I want to publish an event from inside a domain entity like this:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    public User() { }

    public void UpdatePassword(string newPassword)
    {
        ...

        DomainEvents.Publish(new UserPasswordUpdatedEvent() { User = this });

        ...
    }
```

**A possible solution...**

A possible solution is to store the DbContext in the HttpContextand retrieve it from there in the repositories.
So that, the repositoriy instances and the IUnitOfWork instance will be different, but the DbContext used will be the same.

I dont like this solution because I dont want to use the HttpContext.

Maybe having some way to get the current request's  nested container...

Can you show me some light?
Thanks

Comment: You should never publish an event BEFORE the changes are persisted.

Comment: I think that depends of the kind of event we want to publish.

Comment: If you afford to publish a false event

Comment: Some events are transactional, others asynchronic. If I want to send an email after success of a password change, I need to raise the event after commited the changes.
But If I want to decouple another operation using an event maybe I need to perform the action on the same transaction.

Comment: I understand. I don't like to inject services into my domain objects at all, not even event publishers. I yield  (PHP) them. If you can't yield then you can return them. Or you could store them inside the entity and then collect them using a getter.

Comment: You're right, I dont want to inject any service in to my domain. And that is what domain events are, a mechanism to trigger events, and call indirectly others parts of the system.

Comment: A piece of advice, if you want: don't use static calls to application services inside your aggregates/entities, call only side-effects free (and no IO) methods if you need to perform some calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the StructureMap documentation I found this way.

- Use the global root container to create the event handler instances.
- Add a reference to structuremap.web package.
- Configure the UnitOfWork (The DbContext in fact) registry, setting the lifecycle to HttpContextLifecycle in the next way:

  ```
  var container = new Container(_ =>
  {
      _.For(typeof (IUnitOfWork)).Use(typeof (EFUnitOfWork))
          .SetLifecycleTo(new HttpContextLifecycle());
  ```

I'm not totally convinced about this solution, but is better than implement my own UnitOfWork/DbContext storage over the HttpContext.